# Sequelize: How to compare my decrypted values with req.body

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

i am trying to find a user where their mobilenumber = req.body.mobilenumber . the problem i have is that my mobilenumber field in my database is encrypted.

How do i achieve that when i user enters their mobilenumber in the frontend i decrypt the mobilenumbers in my database and check with my req.body.mobilenumber.

I am using Sequelize as my ORM.

I first had this:

```
User.findOne({
               where: {
                       mobilenumber: req.body.countrycode + req.body.mobilenumber,
                       },
               }).then((user) => {
                                   if (user) {
                                               res
                                               .status(400)
                                               .send({ error: "A user with the given mobile number exists." });
                                               return;
                                             }
                                   res.status(201).send(user);
                                 });
```

Then i noticed that my values in my database are encrypted hence all mobilenumbers pass, so i tried the following but it is not working:

```
router.post(
"/",
(req, res) => {      
User.findAll().then((user)=>{

   console.log(user.map(x=>x.mobilenumber))

   const user_mobilenumber=user.map(x=>x.mobilenumber);

   const new_user =req.body.countrycode + req.body.mobilenumber;

const aes256gcm = (key) => {

    const decrypt = (enc) => {
      enc = Buffer.from(enc, "base64");
      const iv = enc.slice(enc.length - 28, enc.length - 16);
      const tag = enc.slice(enc.length - 16);
      enc = enc.slice(0, enc.length - 28);
      const decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-256-gcm', key, iv);
      decipher.setAuthTag(tag);
      let str = decipher.update(enc, null, 'utf8');
      str += decipher.final('utf8');
      return str;
    };
  
    return {
      decrypt,
    };
  };

  const aesCipher = aes256gcm(key);

   user_mobilenumber.forEach((x)=>{
     const y = aesCipher.decrypt(x)
     console.log(y)

     if(new_user===y){
      res.status(400).send({ error: "A user with the given mobile number exists." });
     }
   res.status(201).send(new_user);


   })

 })
});
```

i keep getting this error :

`(node:6456) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client`

Comment: It seems like you are trying to send/set response headers more than once, which is not possible, Can you share complete code?

Comment: @RaghuChahar thank you for your comment, i have updated the question with the complete code, it was just missing the `   res.status(201).send(new_user);` at the bottom

Comment: It's time to use `async` vs. `then()` and it's also time to get that indentation under control.

Comment: @tadman where should i await?

Comment: You use `async` functions and `let result = await x()` instead of `x.then(result => { ... })`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I got it, So the problem is in the forEach part of your code where you are sending response twice i.e

```
if(new_user===y){
      res.status(400).send({ error: "A user with the given mobile number exists." });
     }
   res.status(201).send(new_user);
```

Either return from first if or put the second status send in else block i.e
something like this

```
for (const x of user_mobilenumber) {
  const y = aesCipher.decrypt(x);
  console.log(y);
  if (new_user === y) {
    res.status(400).send({ error: "A user with the given mobile number exists." });
    return;
  }
}

res.status(201).send(new_user);
```

Comment: I am still getting the same error unfortunately.

Comment: Okay, you can't send multiple responses, remove forEach and send response only once, check updated answer.

Comment: The thing is user_mobilenumber returns all the mobile numbers in my database, by doing ` x=user_mobilenumber[0];` i am only picking the first element from the Array

Comment: That works, thanks alot. Do you mind explaining how that worked and not for each? isnt `for (const x of user_mobilenumber)` equivalent to    `user_mobilenumber.forEach((x)=>{}`

Comment: No, ```for (const x of user_mobilenumber)``` can be made synchronous i.e you can break it in between but forEach is asynchronous i.e we can't break it in between.